# Refactor to reduce "frequency" (amount of time) of tiny memory allocation "ClassC[massive]::ClassB[]::int[tiny]"

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, allocation

I want to store `int[]` inside `B` and store `B[]` inside `C`.
There are also other fields that act the same way.

[image]

In a certain run-time situation, I know that all vector (**`.bf1`**,`.bf2`,**`.cf1`**,`.cf2` and `cs`) that created in a code scope  must have certain size (e.g. **`num_bf1`**,`num_bf2`,**`num_cf1`**,`num_cf2` and `num_c`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class B{public:
    std::vector<int> bf1; //b's field 1   <---------
    std::vector<float> bf2;//b's field 2
    //... many of it
};
class C{public:
    std::vector<B> cf1;  // <---------
    std::vector<int> cf2;
    //... many of it
};
int main(){
   //"num_xxx" are known only after some complex algo only at run time.
   //    Their value are also different for each game time-step.
    int num_bf1=3;   // <---------
    int num_bf2=4;
    int num_cf1=2;   // <---------
    int num_cf2=8;
    int num_c=6;
    std::vector<C> cs;
    for(int m=0;m<num_c;m++){
        C c;
        for(int n=0;n<num_cf1;n++){
            B b;
            b.bf1.resize(num_bf1);   // <---------
            b.bf2.resize(num_bf2);
            c.cf1.push_back(b);      // <---------
        }
        c.cf2.resize(num_cf2);
        cs.push_back(c);  // "cs" is now finished as i wish
    }
}
```

It works but this code has an ugly bottleneck.
In real case, the memory allocation alone use **~35% of CPU time**.

### My poor approach

I would like to avoid it by allocate a large memory and split it.

With known values of `num_xxx`, I can calculate amount of `int` that `C::B::bf1` want.

[image]

Therefore, I can `std::vector<int> bf1;  bf1.resize(num_c*num_cf1*num_bf1);` .

Here is the full code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class B{public:
    int* bf1; //b's field 1
    float* bf2;//b's field 2
    //... many of it
};
class C{public:
    B* cf1;
    int* cf2;
    //... many of it
};
```

Here is the new main :-

```
int main(){
    int num_bf1=3;
    int num_bf2=4;
    int num_cf1=2;
    int num_cf2=8;
    int num_c=6;
    std::vector<C> cs;
    std::vector<int> bf1;  bf1.resize(num_c*num_cf1*num_bf1);
    std::vector<float> bf2;  bf2.resize(num_c*num_cf1*num_bf2);
    std::vector<B> cf1;  cf1.resize(num_c*num_cf1);
    std::vector<int> cf2;  bf2.resize(num_c*num_cf2);
    
    for(int m=0;m<num_c;m++){
        C c;
        for(int n=0;n<num_cf1;n++){
            B* b=&(cf1[m*num_cf1+n]);
            b->bf1=&bf1[(m*num_cf1+n)*num_bf1];
            // .... something about bf2 that is hard ...
           
        }
        c.cf1=&(cf1[m*num_cf1+0]);
        // .... something about cf2 that is hard ...
        cs.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

This make my program much faster, but it is so **hard to code**, leads to a nightmare for **maintainability** and **readability**.

### My poor approach V.2

I tried to use a custom stack allocator (and plan to use one-frame allocator).

The issue is that, in multithread, the mutex lock for allocator is called & blocked so often.
A solution is to create 1 stack allocator for each thread.

However, I believe this approach is too low level.  It is a fixing a place to solve the problem in another distanced place.   I think the correct solution is to fix tiny-array creation, not create a library to support such bad practice(?).

### Question

How to solve this tiny-array problem elegantly?

Comment: For your information, [the vector constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) have an overload that allows you to set the size as part of construction. So e.g. `std::vector<int> bf1;  bf1.resize(num_c*num_cf1*num_bf1);` can be replaced by `std::vector<int> bf1(num_c*num_cf1*num_bf1);`

Comment: @Some programmer dude  :: I never know that, thank.

Comment: You might also want to read more about the differences between a vectors *size* and its *capacity*. It might be useful to set its capacity instead of its size sometimes (for example if the stored object has a "heavy" constructor), using the [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) function instead of `resize`.

Comment: Also note that most implementations of vector are pretty smart about allocations. The first few elements might be reallocated one by one, but once a threshold is passed the vector usually allocates memory for more than a single element. Unless you have a rough estimate on the number of elements, it's often better to let the vector handle its allocations by itself. Only start fine-tuning if it's measured to be one of the top-two bottlenecks (and the "performance" isn't up to the actual requirements set).

Comment: @Some programmer dude  :: I agree.  The feature is useful.   In my humble opinion, it can't reduce amount of times of memory allocation, but may reduce amount of memory used per allocation.

Comment: @Some programmer dude :: I heard that some implementation (including mine) is 1 2 4 8 16... It is so nice.

Comment: ... except doubling is notably worse than fibonacci.

Comment: @cppBeginner Have you looked into using jemalloc and more specifically its support for memory arenas?

Comment: @Botje :: Thank for the fibonacci technique, and jemalloc github library.  I never heard about both.   ^^

Comment: @Botje ::  I believe the fault is my own array usage, not the underlying memory allocation (?).

Comment: Using a separate memory arena for this specific data structure gives you 1) isolation from other memory allocation on other threads, 2) a way to instantly free your nested data structure without calling destructors 3) better memory locality

Comment: @Botje :: I am convinced.  Thank.  Edit:: actually I am really convinced. +2

Comment: @Botje  :: With your inspiration (custom allocator advantages), I improve my custom allocator, and the cost almost become zero.  You can post it as a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: I suggest _you_ post a self-answer with the modifications you made and the observations :)